# Programmatically trigger jekyll build errors without a plugin?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to be able to trigger build errors / messages based on problems I detect during jekyll builds of my site.  Basically the equivalent of what I would use assert for in other contexts.  My specific use case is that I construct my site's nav bar by finding all pages whose front matter sets the "show_in_nav_bar" variable set to true.  I want to require that these pages set two other variables as well: "title", which I use as the link text in the nav bar, and "nav_bar_order", which is a sortable value that I use to specify the order the links should be displayed.  I would like to generate an error and have the build fail if either of these variables are missing.  Right now, however, jekyll happily fills in default values, which results in a successful build where the nav bar items are missing (because the text is blank) or mis-ordered.

To make the example concrete, a file with the following front matter should work:

```
---
title: About
show_in_nav_bar: true
nav_bar_order: 1
---
```

But this should generate an error like "title and nav_bar_order are required", and cause the build to fail:

```
---
show_in_nav_bar: true
---
```

Is there a supported way to do this without using a plugin?  I found [this page on jekyll talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-to-properly-indicate-an-error-during-site-generation/447) about how to do this with a plugin, but I'd like to avoid that technique because I'm trying to keep the site as simple as possible, and because I deploy to GitHub Pages, which disallows custom plugins.

Comment: On github pages, you can use continuous integration with custom plugins.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that direction.  Could you elaborate a little bit?  I'm not sure how to set up continuous integration with GitHub pages.  Like what tools I'm supposed to use, or what settings I need to change?

Comment: You can start here https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/travis-ci/